# How can I log Tomcat startup messages to a file?

Tags: tomcat, logging, startup

When I start Tomcat 7 as it tried to deploy an application there are thousands of lines of output, including exceptions, that are printed to the DOS console but not captured in any log file.  I need to see this output and cannot set a large enough buffer in the DOS console to hold it all.

I've tried modifying startup.bat as follows

```
call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS% > tomcat7.log 2>&1
```

but all that does is log a few statements about the Tomcat environment.  All the rest of the startup output is only on the screen.

How do I get Tomcat 7 on Windows to capture its output to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat usually logs its output to either `catalina.out` or a file called `localhost.<date>.log`. Check in Tomcat's logs folder, what you're looking for is probably already there.